# SaltStack-OpenSSL-Pkcs12: How can I convert a generated letsencrypt certificate using saltStack

Tags: openssl, salt-stack, pkcs#12

I'm working on the conversion of a **letsencrypt** certificate to **cert.p12** using **OpenSSL**

This is what I executed manually :

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in $certdir/fullchain.pem -inkey
>   $certdir/privkey.pem -out $certdir/cert_and_key.p12 -name tomcat
>   -CAfile $certdir/chain.pem -caname root -password pass:aaa

My question is how can I make this commande using **saltStack**?
I saw this link :
https://github.com/renoirb/openssl-formula/blob/initial-draft/pillar.example

It's a simple example , pkcs does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no option (module/state) to convert `pem-pcsk12` directly from pillars.

You could create a module or/and state in python that does the conversion for you or you could do it through running the command from yaml:

```
export_pem:
  cmd.run:
    - name: command
```

where command can have the paths and variables you want to define in pillars like:

```
{{ salt['pillar.get']('cert:chain:path') }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , i will apply it and i will tell what's the result